# jasper report integrate in laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel-5, jasper-reports

I have a problem with this integration in Laravel 5:

> Exception in JasperPHP.php line 178:
>   Your report has an error and couldn't be processed! Try to output the command using the function `output();` and run it manually in the console.

Code where exception happens:

```
\JasperPHP::process(
'D:\wamp\www\laravel-Project\reports\center_report.jasper',
false,
array("pdf", "rtf"),
array("php_version" => phpversion()),
$database
)->execute();
```

Comment: I am using Laravel 5 and encountered exactly same error (also line 178). Have you resolved the issue?

Answer (score 1):

They Don't provide a specific package for Laravel5 but you can easily use JasperPHP by following their  instructions https://github.com/cossou/JasperPHP

Comment: Thanks for the reply.                                                                                     I have already use those instruction ,the report already compile 'myreport.jrxml' file to myreport.jasper but the execution command have the describe error.